# How do I create an NHibernate IUserType for a Time in Sql Server 2008/2012?

Tags: nhibernate, nodatime

I am trying to create an NHibernate `IUserType` for the Noda Time `LocalTime` type which would logically map to a `time` type in Sql Server 2008/2012. I am able to get values saving and loading from the database. However, I can't write queries involving comparison of local times like `_session.Query<SchedulingTemplate>().Where(x => x.Start < end && x.End >= start)` gives the error `SqlException (0x80131904): The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the less than operator.`

The relevant code from my user type is:

```cs
public Type ReturnedType
{
    get { return typeof(LocalTime); }
}

public override object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
{
    var dbValue = NHibernateUtil.Time.NullSafeGet(rs, names);
    if(dbValue == null)
        return null;

    return LocalDateTime.FromDateTime((DateTime)dbValue).TimeOfDay;
}

public override void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
{
    if(value == null)
        NHibernateUtil.Time.NullSafeSet(cmd, null, index);
    else
        NHibernateUtil.Time.NullSafeSet(cmd, ((LocalTime)value).LocalDateTime.ToDateTimeUnspecified(), index);
}

public override SqlType[] SqlTypes
{
    get { return new[] { SqlTypeFactory.Time }; }
}
```

The problem is that despite the above code indicating the database type is a time, it generates the following query (per Sql Profiler):

`exec sp_executesql N'select [...] from [SchedulingTemplate] scheduling0_ where scheduling0_.Start<@p0 and scheduling0_.[End]>=@p1',N'@p0 datetime,@p1 datetime',@p0='1753-01-01 20:00:00',@p1='1753-01-01 06:00:00'`

(note I omitted the select list for brevity)

Notice that the type and value of the parameters is being treated as `datetime`.

This appears to be very similar to two NH bugs that have been closed https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2661 and https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2660.

I tried to use `NHibernateUtil.TimeAsTimeSpan` and that didn't seem to work either.  It generated exactly the same query which surprised me.   I am thinking maybe the issue described in NH-2661 also exists for user types and was not fixed for that?

I am using NHibernate v3.3.1.400 and Noda Time 1.0.0-beta2

Comment: until this is fixed you have to implement your own SqlType. Copy the code from TimeType and fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following @Firo's advice, I worked from the time SqlType and came up with this:

```cs
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Dialect;
using NHibernate.SqlTypes;
using NHibernate.Type;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Text;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

[Serializable]
public class LocalTimeType : PrimitiveType, IIdentifierType
{
    private readonly LocalTimePattern _timePattern = LocalTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("h:mm:ss tt");

    public LocalTimeType() : base(SqlTypeFactory.Time) { }

    public override string Name
    {
        get { return "LocalTime"; }
    }

    public override object Get(IDataReader rs, int index)
    {
        try
        {
            if (rs[index] is TimeSpan) //For those dialects where DbType.Time means TimeSpan.
            {
                var time = (TimeSpan)rs[index];
                return LocalTime.Midnight + Period.FromTicks(time.Ticks);
            }

            var dbValue = Convert.ToDateTime(rs[index]);
            return LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dbValue).TimeOfDay;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new FormatException(string.Format("Input string '{0}' was not in the correct format.", rs[index]), ex);
        }
    }

    public override object Get(IDataReader rs, string name)
    {
        return Get(rs, rs.GetOrdinal(name));
    }

    public override Type ReturnedClass
    {
        get { return typeof(LocalTime); }
    }

    public override void Set(IDbCommand st, object value, int index)
    {
        var parameter = ((SqlParameter)st.Parameters[index]);
        parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Time; // HACK work around bad behavior, M$ says not ideal, but as intended, NH says this is a bug in MS may work around eventually
        parameter.Value = new TimeSpan(((LocalTime)value).TickOfDay);
    }

    public override bool IsEqual(object x, object y)
    {
        return Equals(x, y);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(object x, EntityMode entityMode)
    {
        return x.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString(object val)
    {
        return _timePattern.Format((LocalTime)val);
    }

    public object StringToObject(string xml)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml) ? null : FromStringValue(xml);
    }

    public override object FromStringValue(string xml)
    {
        return _timePattern.Parse(xml).Value;
    }

    public override Type PrimitiveClass
    {
        get { return typeof(LocalTime); }
    }

    public override object DefaultValue
    {
        get { return new LocalTime(); }
    }

    public override string ObjectToSQLString(object value, Dialect dialect)
    {
        return "'" + _timePattern.Format((LocalTime)value) + "'";
    }
}
```

The key code is in the `Set` method where is says:

```
var parameter = ((SqlParameter)st.Parameters[index]);
parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Time;
```

This is needed because the MS data provider takes setting the `DbType` to `DbType.Time` to mean the underlying type should be `DateTime`. You **must** set the **`SqlDbType`** to time for it to work.

Comment: Converting from a `TimeSpan` to a `LocalTime` should be much cleaner than it is. I've raised issue 148 for this. Converting from a `DateTime` to a `LocalTime` *is* simpler than shown - you just go via `LocalDateTime`: `LocalTime time = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dateTime).TimeOfDay;`

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet I've made the change to use `LocalDateTime.FromDateTime`